# lookup_field Return None In Django get_queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I have a class extend with GenericAPIView ,

I Can access to the lookup_field in my functions, but I can't use it in the queryset function.

```
class SellerItemAPIView(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin):
    serializer_class = ShopItemSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    lookup_field = 'phone_number'

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.lookup_url_kwarg) # It Return None
        print(self.lookup_field) # It Return 'phone_number'
        shop_items = ShopItem.objects.filter(Q(seller_id__user_id__phone_number=self.lookup_field))
        return shop_items


    def get(self, request, phone_number):
        result = self.list(request, phone_number)
        print(result.status_code)
        return result
```

How Can I Access to the lookup_field in get_queryset ?

Comment: please, add your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

Remove this line from class:

```py
lookup_field = 'phone_number'
```

Get the `lookup_field` in `get_queryset`, like this:

```py
phone_number = self.kwargs.get('phone_number')
```